# Finding a bound on the difference of the products of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve the following question.

Suppose we have $(a_k)_{k=1}^N$ and $(b_k)_{k=1}^N$ satisfying $|a_k-b_k|\leq \delta$ for all $k$, and also that $a_k, b_k \in [0,1]$ for all $k$.

Let $A=\Pi_{k}a_k$, and $B =\Pi_{k}b_k$.  Then I want to find a bound on the difference $|A-B|$. I know that the largest value that $B$ can take is $ \Pi_{k}(a_k+\delta)$, and so $B-A$ in this case can be upper bounded by $\sum_{k=1}^N {N \choose k}\delta^k \leq (1+\delta)^N$. But this is useless as it is even greater than both $A$ and $B$.

Is it possible to obtain a bound which goes to zero as  $\delta$ is made smaller for a fixed $N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity take $N=2$ and notice:

$$
|a_1a_2-b_1b_2|=|a_1a_2-((b_1-a_1)+a_1)b_2|=|a_1a_2-[b_2(b_1-a_1)+a_1b_2]
$$
$$
=|a_1(a_2-b_2)-b_2(b_1-a_1)|\leq |a_2-b_2|+|b_1-a_1| \leq 2\delta 
$$ 
I'm using here $|a_k|,|b_k| \leq 1$, that's not the condition you gave, but if we only suppose $a_k,b_k \in (-\infty, 1]$ I don't believe this will be true, if that's what you're asking about I can try to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention the condition that $a_k \geq 0$. I will update it in the question.

Comment: great, by induction you can generalize (just checked on paper, it goes through fine) that $|A-B| \leq N\delta$.

Comment: I can also see that now. We get it by replacing $a_1$ and $b_1$ with $A_{N-1}$ and $B_{N-1}$ , and $a_2$ and $b_2$ with $a_N$ and $b_N$ respectively. Thanks again!